# Convert UTC time to Local time of Browser

Tags: node.js, datetime, utc

I am getting UTC time format,I need to change it in Local time of browser.I have tried the following:-

```
var start_time1= new Date(matchData.results[i].start_time);
```

where `matchData.results[i].start_time` is my UTC time i.e. `ISODate("2017-03-09T03:30:00Z")`

After doing above I am getting:

**09:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)**

But what I want is like, if local browser time is 9:00 a.m., it gives me the same, i.e. 9:00 a.m.

Comment: You need to do this with JavaScript on the clientside.

Comment: Check out https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try :

`var start_time1 = new Date("2017-03-09T03:30:00Z");`

`console.log(start_time1)`

`>>Thu Mar 09 2017 04:30:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)`

(I'm based in France)